# WordPress: functions.php is not in array error message

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I do have the following code:

```
add_filter('upload_mimes','restrict_mimes_for_subscriber');

function restrict_mimes_for_subscriber($mimes) {
  if (! current_user_can('delete_posts')) {
    return;
  }

    $mimes = array(
    'pdf' => 'application/pdf',
    'jpg|jpeg' => 'image/jpeg'
    );

  return $mimes;
}
```

and I want to add an error message if the uploaded file is not in the array of allowed mimes for a subscriber. The below snippet is what I found already

```
if (! in_array("uploaded-file", $mimes)) {
    echo "Error: Only PDF and JPG files allowed.";
}
```

But I do not know how I get the "uploaded-file" to compare it against the array? Any help to complete my code please?
And I think the snippet has to go into my code just before the return statement or?

Many thanks and cheers

Yogie